# Jumble anagram longest word python

Tags: python, algorithm

This algorithm will input for a number then return how many anagrams have that length in the dictionary from a `.txt` file. I am getting an output of 6783 if i enter a 5 when I should be getting 5046 based on my list. I do not know what else to change.

ex: An input of 5 should return 5046

I also have been trying to search through the list with an input of a positive integer for the word length, to collect words with the maximum amount of anagrams, I have no idea where to start.

ex: An input of 4 for word length should return the maximum amount of anagrams which is 6, and outputs the list of anagrams, e.g

`[’opts’, ’post’, ’pots’, ’spot’, ’stop’, ’tops’]`

```
def maxword():
    input_word = int(input("Enter word length (hit enter key to quit):"))

word_file = open("filename", "r")

word_list = {}
alist = []
for text in word_file:
    simple_text = ''.join(sorted(text.strip()))
    word_list.update({text.strip(): simple_text})
count = 0
for num in word_list.values():
    if len(num) == input_word:
        count += 1
        alist.append(num)
return str(input_word) + str(len(alist))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with a single pass of the input text file. Your idea to sort the word and store it in a map is the right approach.

Build a dictionary with the sorted word as the key since it will be same for all anagrams and a list of the words having same sorted word as the key as the values.

To avoid looping over the dictionary again we'll keep track of the key having the largest length as it's value.

If building this `word_list` dictionary is for one time use only for specific length then you can consider only words having the `input_word` length for the dictionary.

```
word_file = ["abcd", "cdab", "cdab", "cdab", "efgh", "ghfe", "fehg"]
word_list = {}
alist = []
input_word = 4
max_len = -1
max_word = ""
for text in word_file:
    if len(text) == input_word:
        simple_text = ''.join(sorted(text.strip()))
        if simple_text not in word_list:
            word_list.update({simple_text: [text.strip()]})
        else:
            word_list[simple_text].append(text.strip())
        if(len(word_list[simple_text]) > max_len):
            max_len = len(word_list[simple_text])
            max_word = simple_text
print(max_word)
print(word_list[max_word])
```